# Complex Integration on a simple closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $a\in\Bbb C $ with $\vert a \vert\lt 1 $ then,
what is the value of
\begin{equation}   
    \frac {(1-\vert a \vert ^2)}{\pi}\int_C \frac {\vert dz \vert}{\vert z+a \vert^2}  
\end{equation}
where C is simple closed curve $\vert z \vert =1 $ taken with positive orientation.

I tried this problem but I am not getting integral of mod function  and how to solve this problem. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1-|a|^2}\pi\int_C\frac{|\mathrm{d}z|}{|z+a|^2}
&=\frac{1-|a|^2}\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(|a|+\cos(\theta))^2+\sin^2(\theta)}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{1-|a|^2}\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{|a|^2+1+2|a|\cos(\theta)}\tag{2}\\
&=2\frac{1-|a|^2}\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{|a|^2+1+2|a|\cos(\theta)}\tag{3}\\
&=2\frac{1-|a|^2}\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^2}}{|a|^2+1+2|a|\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\tag{4}\\
&=4\frac{1-|a|^2}\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(1+|a|)^2+(1-|a|)^2u^2}\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=\left.\frac4\pi\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-|a|}{1+|a|}u\right)\right]_0^\infty\tag{6}\\[12pt]
&=2\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $z=\frac{a}{|a|}e^{i\theta}$
$(2)$: $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1$
$(3)$: use symmetry
$(4)$: [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)
$(5)$: algebra
$(6)$: arctangent integral
$(7)$: evaluate

Comment: Thanks to robjohn for your help.I got it.

Comment: But how to think of  these kind of substitution of z?

Comment: Mainly: experience. However, perhaps a bit of motivation can be given. For $(1)$, $z=e^{i\theta}$ is a standard parametrization of the unit circle. The $\frac{a}{|a|}$ just allows us to start with $a$ at $\theta=0$; then we can rotate everything by multiplying by $\frac{|a|}{a}$. The Weierstrass substitution is a very useful tool for turning trigonometric integrals into rational polynomial integrals.